# Where can I download odoo 9 addons for enterprise?

Tags: odoo-9

Please help,
where can I get odoo 9 addons for enterprise ?
I am using windows.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Goto https://www.odoo.com/buy and register with your details and will get a link to get you addons. When you subscribe to Odoo Enterprise, it will include an activation code for a single production database, access to Odoo bug fixing service, security advisories (2 weeks before their public release) and access to Odoo database upgrade service.

You can find a complete description of the included services in the Odoo Enterprise Subscription Agreement

You can also view their pricing schemes https://www.odoo.com/pricing

Answer (score 1):

You must have an Odoo Enterprise contract. Then you will be provided access to the Enterprise add-ons.